# Como faço upload de um arquivo para uma pasta especifica dentro de um container blob azure

Tags: c#, microsoft-azure, blob

Preciso enviar um arquivo para umas pasta que fica dentro do container do azure.

Consigo enviar para a pasta raiz, porem não  consegui enviar para dentro da pasta especifica.

Segue meu código, onde envio para a Raiz.

```
var connectionString = "xxxxxxx";
string containerName = "projetos";
var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
var containerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
var path2 = @"C:\2021\BlobContainer\";
var fileName2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyyHHmm") + ".txt";
var localFile = Path.Combine(path2, fileName2);
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName2);
Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage");
using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFile);
await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
uploadFileStream.Close();
```

Tentei colocar diretamenta na `string containerName = "projetos";` como `string containerName = "projetos/Pasta1";` porem sem sucesso.

Como eu faço para enviar para uma pasta especifica chamada Pasta1 dentro do container projetos ?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2):

Resolvido!

Conforme observado neste post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742201/how-to-save-a-file-to-a-subfolder-in-an-azure-blob-container

É necessario mudar:

```
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName2);
```

Para

```
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("Pasta1/" + fileName2);
```

Ficando o código assim:

```
var connectionString = "xxxxxx";
string containerName = "projetos";
var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
var containerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
var path2 = @"C:\CMSP2021\HUB_Integracao\";
var fileName2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyyHHmm") + ".txt";
var localFile = Path.Combine(path2, fileName2);
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("Pasta1/" + fileName2);
Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage");
using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFile);
await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
uploadFileStream.Close();
```

Fica a dica !!!